# How to after post make an redirect with params in JSF2??

Tags: jsf

I have this situation:

My model

```
public class Model {
    int id;
    String desc;
}
```

my managed bean with request scope

```
@Request
@ManagedBean(name = "bean")
public class ModelMB {

    Model model; // with getter/setter

    public void action(){
        dao.persistWithRefresh(model);
        return sucess;
    }
}
```

and my facesconfig with navigation cases

faces-config.xml

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/nutri/signin.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>sucess</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/nutri/show.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect include-view-params="true">
            <view-param>
                <name>id</name>
                <value>#{bean.model.id}</value>
            </view-param>
        </redirect>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

but in page show.xhtml id param after post submit is empty.. WHY? ;(

Comment: In JSF-2, just `return "show?faces-redirect=true&id=" + model.getId();`

Comment: and using faces-config??

Comment: @user155542 How are you able to `return sucess` in a method with a `void` return type?

Comment: Please post your show.xhtml ?